# Keras API model in compute_output_shape raise NotImplementedError NotImplementedError

Tags: keras, model

I want to implement a complex model which has multi-inputs and multi-outputs. So I can only implement it use Keras.models.Model.

keras == 2.2.4
tensorflow == 1.13.1

But I get this Error:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263:
>   colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version.
>
> Instructions for updating:
>
> Colocations handled automatically by placer.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3326, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('G:/JupyterWorkSpace/InfosExtractor/code/BERT/ModelTest.py',
>   wdir='G:/JupyterWorkSpace/InfosExtractor/code/BERT')
>
> File "G:\PyCharm\PyCharm
>   2018.3.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
>       pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
>
> File "G:\PyCharm\PyCharm
>   2018.3.4\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>       exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "G:/JupyterWorkSpace/InfosExtractor/code/BERT/ModelTest.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       out = myModel(input)
>
> File "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 474, in **call**
>       output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
>
> File "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line
>   587, in compute_output_shape
>
> ```
> raise NotImplementedError
> ```
>
> NotImplementedError

And I found that these subclass's _is_graph_network is False.That I find code in keras.network:

```
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
     if not self._is_graph_network:
         # Must be implemented by subclasses.
         raise NotImplementedError
```

I can't find some examples about "# Must be implemented by subclasses" as well.

A simple example like:

```
from keras import Model, Input, losses
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dense1 = Dense(256)

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        out = self.dense1(inputs)
        return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = Input(shape=(256,))
    myModel = MyModel()
    out = myModel(input)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=out)
    model.compile(optimizer=SGD, loss=losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy)
```

Comment: This is like trying to make Keras work like Pytorch. You don't need to subclass the model in keras. There are plenty of answers about how to create multi-input, multi-output models without subclassing.

Comment: Without subclassing, I succeeded to create the model and it work well. Although the code look like more longer, but it indeed work well.Thx

Comment: And I still have a question that why it doesn't work by this way?

Comment: Because you need to implement the `compute_output_shape` method.